# Excel Copy / Paste over and over

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have some data in my Excel file that I want to run a loop for, because I tend to paste from a site and want to sort it out to analyze.

The information I'm copying over is in a table format, but when I paste the text into Excel, it pastes it all in one line. Not only that, it throws it all off.

So, from the website, it shows up as follows:

```
Item 1 Action 1 Action 2 Action 3
yada       1       0        0
blada      5       0        0
rada       3       0        0
etc...
```

When I paste it over, it shows up as follows:

```
Item 1  
Action 1  
Action 2  
Action 3  
yada  
1  
0  
0  
blada  
5  
0  
0  
rada  
3
0
0
etc...
```

Is there a simple formula that I can use to run a loop to get the number underneath each item, paste it in the cell next to it, and stop when there is an empty cell?

When it's all said and done, it creates 892 lines, of which I only really need a quarter of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `A135` & fill it down.

  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$130:$D$133,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS($A$130:$D$133)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS($A$130:$D$133),COLUMNS($A$130:$D$133))+1),"")`

**N.B.** You may also assign **NAME** to the Range `A130:D133`.

[image]

- Then in above Formula replace `$A$130:$D$133` with `Mydata`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*